# Microsoft SCCM 2016 (Build 1606) - Deploying software updates to server group collections

Tags: sccm

In Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager 2016 (Build 1606), there is a pre-release feature for collections called Server Groups which allows for cluster aware updating. When deploying software updates for this feature to work (and prevent a cluster from going down), is it necessary to create deployments for each Server Group collection individually, or would it be possible to create a collection of Server Group collections, and have the software update deployments target the collection of Server Group collections?

[image]

Comment: Hi! There is no SCCM 2016, as it's on a quarterly release cadance now. Can you clarify what build you are on, as it may influence the answer? For example: SCCM 1511 or SCCM 1602.

Comment: I just called it what it is on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads/?#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=666&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0). Technically I suppose it is on the one product in SC 2016 which doesnt have a year in its name. Anyways it is SCCM build 1606.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build 1606 is called System Center Configuration Manager (Current Branch) 1606.

There were some issues so it's now been moved to pre-release status. (You can see features on the Administration - Cloud Services - Updates and Servicing - Features. If it's not enabled and you want to enable it, be sure in Hierarchy Settings, 'Consent to use Pre-release features' is enabled before you enable the feature )

The Server Group Settings are configured in the properties of a device collection. You can put your 'desired' systems (what ever cluster or normal systems) in a device collection and then configure server group settings on this device collection.

The software update deployment is **using the typical deployment process**. The Server Group configuration adds functions that you can control:

- Allow a percentage of machines to be updated at the same time
- Allow a number of machines to be updated at the same time
- Specify the maintenance sequence (ordering)
- Configure PowerShell scripts to run custom actions before and after your deployments.

In case that you have got a collection with child collections, the settings of a parent collection is separated and has nothing to do with a child collection configuration. The parent collection just read the memberships of a child collection, not the other configuration.

As I said, as long as all your desired system is member of the collection, you can do the configuration.

Comment: My question was wether or not a parent collection of collections honor the Server Group settings of the child collections. Could you address that?

Comment: No. it doesn't. The settings of a parent collection is separated and has nothing to do with a child collection configuration. In your case, the parent collection just read the memberships of a child collection, not the other configuration.

Comment: Thank you. You should add this to your answer, and it was what my question was about.